# Python high level socket commnication

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, localhost, communication

I am currently implementing a data processing prototype. As part of that I need some communication between two parties. This should be a proof of work only and for that I would like to exchange a few simple messages using my localhost (again the main focus is not on the message exchange but rather on the functionality of the two parties who communicate).

I found myself stuck with relatively low-level [socket](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html) implementations. Is there a higher level alternative?

ideally I would like to do something like this:

```
# clien1
clt = some_socket(localhost, 1234)
clt.on_message() # handle a message
clt2 = some_socket(localhost, 5678)
clt2.send('hi from first client')
```

and the other client...

```
# clien2
clt = some_socket(localhost, 5678)
clt.on_message() # handle a message
clt2 = some_socket(localhost, 1234)
clt2.send('hi from second client2')
```

and now client1 would output `'hi from client2'` and client2 would output `'hi from client1'`.

If someone knows a better way than to use sockets, go right on...

Comment: Check out https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/socketserver.html -- sounds similar to what you describe.

Comment: sounds good. Will have a look